# Dynamically add React attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently rendering two types of checkboxes (checked or unchecked) depending on some logic. As you can see this code is not very DRY, since the only difference between the two lines is the `defaultValue` attribute.

```
if (user.surveyData.device.indexOf(device) > -1) {
    devicesList.push(<li key={i}><input type="checkbox" className="device" value="DK2" defaultChecked/>{ device }</li>)
} else {
    devicesList.push(<li key={i}><input type="checkbox" className="device" value="DK2"/>{ device }</li>)
}
```

Is there any way I can do this a little more DRY-ly?

Comment: I answered to a question very similar to this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163693/how-to-conditionally-add-attributes-to-react-components/31164090#31164090

Comment: defaultChecked={user.surveyData.device.indexOf(device) > -1}

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks guys. marked this one as a duplicate