# Why does jsx require three dots in this code?

Tags: babeljs, reactjs

I found a [much upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35428331) to a question with the following code:

```
var condition = true;

return (
  <Button {...condition ? {bsStyle: 'success'} : {}} />
);
```

Why is the ... required? If I omit it, babel complains to me that:

```
repl: Unexpected token, expected ...
```

It looks like the spread syntax, but `condition` is a boolean. I'm having trouble finding docs that explain what is going on.

Comment: It is JSX spread. The `...` has lower precedence, so the conditional operator expression is evaluated first and then the returned object (either the one with `bsStyle` property or the empty one) is spread.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/07bbe37bc42b6d4aef81

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you check out [MDN: Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

> The spread syntax **allows an expression** to be expanded in places where
>   multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for
>   array literals) or multiple variables  (for destructuring assignment)
>   are expected.

If you see, the spread operator inside the jsx syntax to evaluate expression, then

```
<Button {...condition ? {bsStyle: 'success'} : {}} />
```

Would become something like, `(after babel run with react bootstrap example)`:

`_react2.default.createElement(_reactBootstrap.Button, condition ? { bsStyle: 'success' } : {})`

It can also be written as:

```
<Button bsStyle={condition ? 'success' : ''}  />
```

Which, then *means you are passing the props `bsStyle` with empty string*.

So in order to conditionally pass the props itself, you can leverage the spread operator and evaluate the expression. This helps us to pass multiple props on with conditions:

```
<Button {...condition ? {bsStyle: 'success', bsSize:"large"} : {}} />
```

Rather than:

```
<Button bsStyle={condition ? 'success' : ''} bsSize={condition ? 'large' : ''} />
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a **boolean** to *return an object*. The spread operator `...` usage is for spreading that object, so you can make it more readable for yourself by using parenthesis:

```
var condition = true;
<Button { ...(condition ? {bsStyle: 'success'} : {}) } />
```

Which is equivalent to this, if your variable is true:

```
<Button { ...{bsStyle: 'success'} } />
```

or this one if your variable is false:

```
<Button { ...{} } />
```