# error in react when using semantic ui table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I using semantic UI to create a table. 
 I want to set table row property to `positive`. like this :

```
<Table.Row positive>
```

here is my code:

```
  <Table.Row {this.props.email.success ? "positive" : "negative"}>
```

but this error is occure :

```
./src/components/EmailItem.js
Syntax error: ... src/components/EmailItem.js: Unexpected token, expected ... (7:18)

   5 |   render() {
   6 |     return (
>  7 |       <Table.Row {this.props.email.success ? "positive" : "negative"}>
     |                   ^
   8 |         <Table.Cell>
   9 |           {this.props.email.from}
  10 |         </Table.Cell>
```

how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<Table.Row positive={!!this.props.email.success} negative={!this.props.email.success}>
```

And check this - [How to conditionally add attributes to React components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163693/how-to-conditionally-add-attributes-to-react-components)