# Adding an attribute in a <div> if the attribute has value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am new to web development, so this is probably pretty fundamental. I want to add a data attribute to the div tag if the datainfo prop variable is not empty

```
<div style={{height: props.height - handleHeight()}} data={datainfo ? datainfo : ""}>
```

But right now the data attribute is added with an empty value if the datavalue is empty. Instead I want it to not appear in the div tag at all.

Can I add the whole thing in the JSX clause or how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31164090/2831645), you should put `false` instead of `""`.

```
<div style={{height: props.height - handleHeight()}} data={datainfo ? datainfo : false}>
```

Comment: You should add that `null` and `undefined` are acceptable values as well. Personally, I'd rather use `null` here, rather than `false`. But that's just my preference.

Comment: Thanks. data={datainfo} seems to work. But data={datainfo ? datainfo : false} does not. It results in data=false