# How to make the existance of an html attribute dynamic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following code, I want to make the "checked" attribute of the `input` dynamic. Obviously `completed` is a boolean. The compilation fails right at the start of `{check}` with the error `TS1005: '...' expected.`

```
import React from 'react';

export class TodoListItem extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    const {label, completed} = this.props;
    const check = completed? "checked": " ";
    return (
      <li className="todo">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"  {check}/> {label}
        </label>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditionally add attributes to React components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163693/how-to-conditionally-add-attributes-to-react-components)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly pass checked={completed} so if completed is true checkbox will be checked otherwise unchecked.

```
import React from 'react';

export class TodoListItem extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    const {label, completed} = this.props;
    return (
      <li className="todo">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"  checked={completed} /> {label}
        </label>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```