# Ternary inside input react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do a ternary as you can see below (not working) and surprised to find there isn't a SO answer that I can find. What's the right way of doing a ternary for an attribute inside html tags in react? I just want required to be added if id == 1

```
import React from 'react'

const Word = ({onRemoveWord, id, onChangeWord}) => {
  return (
    <div>
       <input 
          type="text" 
          { id === 1 ? required : null}
          name="word" 
          id={id} 
          onChange={(e) => {onChangeWord(e)}} 
        /> 
        <span onClick={() => {onRemoveWord(id)}} className="deletebtn">-</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Word
```

Comment: What's the output you're expecting? If you're trying to conditionally set an attribute, did you want `required={id === 1}`?

Comment: What's your desired result?

Comment: I think he wants the `required` attribute if `id === 1`, and no such attribute otherwise

Comment: your attribute should look like `<input required={ id === 1}/>`

Comment: Then see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/31163693/3001761, you don't need a ternary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe mentiond above,

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    required={id===1}
    name="word" 
    id={id} 
    onChange={(e) => {onChangeWord(e)}} 
/>
```

If you need to add another attribute based on id,  you can add like below.

```
<button className={id===1 ? "primary" : "second"}>
    MyButton
</button>
```

Comment: this works!.. so does this mean required=0 and required=1 turn off and on the required functionality?

Comment: from the linked article.. "Apparently, for certain attributes, React is intelligent enough to omit the attribute if the value you pass to it is not truthy." woah