# Is there a way to prevent an event to be triggered based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling, dom-events

I am building a ReactJS App and I have a function that is called after a click, however I want this click event to be triggered only if the screen width is larger than 1200px.

For example, in the code below I have an `onClick` event added to the `subContainer` element, I'd like to prevent this `onClick` to be triggered if the screen width is smaller than 1200px.

Is there a way to do that without using a listener?

I know I could use a listener and set a condition to determine whether this event would be listened or not; I also know that I could set the condition within the function and prevent the logic to be executed; and I also could create two different JSX elements (one without the event) and render one or another based on my condition. But what I want is to keep the `onClick` on the element (without `addEventListener`) and prevent it to be triggered

It would be something like that: `<div screenWidth > 1200 ? onClick="..." : null>Test</div>`. Of course, this doesn't work.

Is this possible?

P.S. Remember, I am using React, this code is just an example.

```js
const test = () => {
  console.log('Test')
}
```

```css
.subContainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="subContainer" onClick="test()">Test<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe something like `onClick={window.screen.width > 1200 ? test() : () => console.log('Not true')}` or inside your test function `if(window.screen.width > 1200) do stuff`

Comment: Yes, I could do that. But what I want is to prevent the event to be triggered and not change what will be called.

Comment: I think this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68421971/10213537, may be the better solution, where condition is `window.screen.width > 1200`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  console.log(window.screen.width);
  let myCondition = window.screen.width > 1200;
  console.log(myCondition);
  const clickThis = () => {
    console.log("hello");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={ myCondition ? clickThis : null}
      >
        Hello CodeSandbox
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, apparently it is window.screen.width not window.screenWidth.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-dust-1l894?file=/src/App.js:0-247)

Comment: I see that if `myCondition` is false the function won't be called, but wouldn't the `event` being triggered anyway?

Comment: Sorry, i was trying out multiple ways. Revised to my first answer. Nothing gets triggered this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hook to listen to window size and pass the function based on the width inside onClick

```
function App() {
  const size = useWindowSize();
  return (
    <div class="container">
      <div class="subContainer" onClick={size.width > 1200 ? test : null}>
        Test
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a link to simple [useWindow hook](https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/)

Comment: The OP wants screen width, which is a different property from window.innerWidth and innerHeight, the `useWindowSize` hook is unecessary because screen width doesn't change.

Comment: I have no problems getting the screen or window width, I just need to know if this `null` prevent the event to be triggered?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31164090/10213537) setting an attribute to false causes react to omit it from the HTML which may cause the event from not being called to begin with, so perhaps using `onClick={window.screen.width > 1200 ? function() : false}` is the best method.