# Conditionally add attribute to HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have an anchor tags with some attributes but I need to add an attribute based on some attribute.
For example -

```
     <a
        
        className={someName}
        onContextMenu={handleClick}
      >
```

I need onContextMenu to be present only if some condition is true. Something like this -

```
     <a
        
        className={someName}
        if (true) ? onContextMenu={handleClick} : ''
      >
```

How can I achieve it?  Coding in Typescript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I conditionally add attributes to React components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163693/how-do-i-conditionally-add-attributes-to-react-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either move your boolean logic into the assignment of the property:

```js
<a onContextMenu={true ? handleClick : null} />
```

or you could potentially move the boolean logic into the event handler itself

```js
const handleClick = (e) => {
  if(!true) return;

  // Do other stuff
}
```