conditionally add prop to a jsx element
I have a react app and am trying to pass down a prop to a jsx element based on a condition. The element in question is an anchor tag and if the condition is true I would like to pass a rel="noreferrer" but if it is false I don't want to pass down anything...
Like <a {...thisCondtion} or something of that  nature.
Is there a specific way to do this?
Assume the condition either renders true or null (&& ternary) how would I pass down that prop correctly.

Does this answer your question? How do I conditionally add attributes to React components?

well the Boolean whether or not to add the prop won't be in the prop

@Yehuda did you see the other answers, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35428331/5648954, the boolean doesn't need to be in the prop.

Should be able to just pass undefined
<MyElement optionalProp={condition ? 123 : undefined} />

Although I guess you could also do
const props = condition ? { optionalProp: 123 } : {}

<MyElement {...props} />

